# Find all positive integers such that: $n^2-3|3n^3-5n^2+7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find all positive integers such that: $$n^2-3|3n^3-5n^2+7.$$

I did the following:
$$n^2-3|3n^3-5n^2+7,n^2-3\Rightarrow n^2-3|3n^3-5n^2+7,3n^3-9n$$
$$\Rightarrow n^2-3|5n^2-9n-7,5n^2-15\Rightarrow n^2-3|9n-8$$
Now we must have:  $9n-8\geq n^2-3$.We should determine the sign of  $n^2-9n+5$, but the equation: $n^2-9n+5=0$ does not have integer roots.How can we proceed?

Comment: If $9n-8\ge n^2-3$ then $9n\ge n^2+5>n^2$ and so $9>n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing from $\,n^2\!-\!3\mid 9n\!-\!8\ $ we can avoid quadratic inequalities and checking $n = 1,\ldots,8$

$\!\bmod n^2\!-3\!:\ \color{#c00}{n^2\equiv 3}\,\Rightarrow\, 0 \equiv \color{#c00}{n}(9\color{#c00}{n}\!-\!8)\equiv {27}\!-\!8n\,\Rightarrow\,0\equiv 9n\!-\!8+27\!-\!8n \equiv n\!+\!19\,$ hence $\,n\equiv -19\,$ so $\,0\equiv 8\!-9n\equiv 179\,$ is prime, so its divisor $\,n^2\!-\!3 = \pm1,\pm 179,\,$ so $\,n = 2.$

Comment: With $179$ it's indeed nice!

Comment: In other words we use the analog of the Euclidean gcd algorithm in the ring $\mathbb Z[x]$ of polynomials with integer co-efficients to show there are $f(x), g(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ with $(x^2-3)f(x)+(x^3-5x^2+7)g(x)=179$.....................+1.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $n^2-9n+5\leq0$, which gives $1\leq n\leq8$ and check it.

$n=2$ is valid.

Comment: You mean we should check $n=1,2,...,8$ one by one? Is there any shorter way?

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi I think it's short enough.

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: If you had ended up with say n^2 - 3 divides 865n + 2345 with many more candidates, you would check n = 1, 2, 3 upwards, but also solve (865n + 2345) = k * (n^2 - 3) for k = 1, 2, 3, etc until both sides meet.

Comment: @Hamid Yes, there is a shorter way that avoids checking all those cases - see my answer.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque I think it's better just to check $8$ numbers. It takes less time.

Comment: @Michael Maybe for you, but for me its much faster the way I did it (and that way works far more generally since it doesn't use results depending on real numbers and/or ordering)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque I think for you it's also better. I mean for this problem, of course.

Comment: @Michael What does that mean?

Comment: @Bill Dubuque You are right, but this problem so easy, that we can see $n=2$ immediately.

Comment: To clarify, using pure divisibility laws (vs. inequalities) as I did shows that the inference $\,n^2\!-\!3\mid 2n^3\!-\!5n^2\!+\!7\,\Rightarrow\, n^2\!-\!3\mid 179\,$ is true in *every* commutative ring. We can't obtain such general results using inequalities since generally rings are not ordered.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque It's amazing! I think we can create something nice.

Comment: @Michael Others may be interested in such generality - even if you are not, i.e. to clarify, my comments are not targeted specifically at you, but to anyone reading. Of course there are often many ways to tackle problems, and we can learn from them all. Enjoy.